# Is there a Matlab tool similar to Python's Doctest?

Tags: testing, matlab, doctest

In my Python development, `doctest` has really helped both to

- make writing unit tests less annoying, and
- integrate usage examples with documentation.

I was wondering, is there anything like this available in the Matlab world?  It doesn't have to literally use code comments as a test, but if it had those two desirable qualities, that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exists now!  There are three versions out there:

- An [Octave-compatible version that still gets some development](https://github.com/catch22/octave-doctest)
- A [version of Matlab-xUnit with an integrated doctest runner](https://github.com/psexton/matlab-xunit)
- The [original version from 2010](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28862), which is self-contained and emits results in [TAP](https://testanything.org/) format

Comment: A-ha, that's what I wrote :-)  But it's a good idea to link it here in case anyone ever looks for it.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but there is something to generate documentation called **[M2HTML](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/)**.

It is very useful, and you can take a look at the examples at that page to see how wonderful results it's producing (even dependency graphs :) ).

For unit testing in MATLAB, even if there are many solutions, **[mlUnit](http://mlunit.dohmke.de/Main_Page)** was the most efficient to me.

Comment: I'm actually already using m2HTML, you're right, it's very good.  I was hoping to be able to add usage examples that would be automatically validated, and test the code at the same time.

Thanks for the mlUnit recommendation

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent to `doctest` in MATLAB.

There is, however, a nice unit testing framework on the [Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846).

Comment: I've seen xUnit's existence.. I was really hoping for something that would integrate with documentation, though.

Comment: If I wrote a clone of `doctest` for Matlab, by your best guess, do you think others would be interested in using it?

Comment: I would think that this would have a decent chance of eventually making the `pick of the week` of the File Exchange. In other words: I believe that others would be very interested in this.